Html.fromHTML in Android has style problems with nested text?
Code:
private void initTextView(){
    String html = "<html><body><span style=\"color:green\">In the name of <span style=\"color:blue\"><b> God</b></span>the compassionate, the merciful</span></body><html>";
    TextView htmlTextView = findViewById(R.id.html_text);
    htmlTextView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
}

The UI behaves differently than the browser, while browser' behaviour is what I expect. The color of word God should be the blue, but it is green!
I found a similar problem(Android Html.fromHtml() does not work correctly on nested text style) 11 years ago, but it has been not solved yet.
